# How to automate the creation of a Joomla user with the Steam API

Tags: php, joomla, steam-web-api

Hope you are all well. I have very little knowledge in coding so any help is very much appreciated.

I am currently using the following steam authentication system on my joomla website. https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication

The login system works perfectly (apart from the logout button but that is for later), however the issue is that when a user signs-in through steam, the user is not created in joomla, so my other joomla plugins (such as Alphauser points) do not respond to the user being logged in. There is no syncing with the steam login.

I am wondering if there is anyway that the steamID and the password can be pulled from the steam login in order to automatically create a linked joomla user (steamid as username), and if possible to create a random email address or even copy the email from steam.

Thank you in advance.

Joe

Comment: So you have made an authentication plugin .. have you made (or looked at) the user plugin?

Comment: Hi. I didn't make the authentication plugin. And I am using the default joomla user login. I just have no idea how I can link the steam authentication with joomla to create a new user once they have authenticated through steam.

Comment: Sorry, technically I did make the plugin by using sourcerer and pasting the php code provided on github. But I did not write the code.

Comment: So that's what you need to do. Make a real steam authentication plugin.  Follow the pattern you see for ldap or google.   Authentication and authorization are way to serious to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the password from Steam, that would be silly.

What you *can* do is use the Steam API as an authentication mechanism. If a user authenticates through Steam create a user in your database (steam-id + username).

I don't think you can ask Steam for the user email. Maybe there's an integrated option for it (like how OpenID can request for certain data like name and email). Otherwise you'll have to ask the user for it on first signin.

This approach is generic, it's not at all specific to Joomla or Steam.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up. Would you happen to know how I would go about the system of creating a joomla user once they are authenticated through steam?